# @ManyToOne relationship is not audited

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_a")
@Audited
public class EntityA {

    @Column(name = "entity_a_uuid", columnDefinition = "char", updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    /**
     * @deprecated in favor of uuid
     */
    @Deprecated
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "entity_a_id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_a_id", nullable = false)
    @BatchSize(size = 100)
    @NotAudited
    private List<EntityB> entityBs = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "entity_b")
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "entity_b_uuid", columnDefinition = "char", updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_a_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private EntityA entityA;
}
```

Each is correctly audited into two tables `entity_a_audit` and `entity_b_audit`. However, the `entity_a_id` field in `entity_b_audit` is *always* null.

Some details:

1. If I do not have the `@NotAudited` in `EntityA`, I will get an error that says something to the effect of: The table `EntityA_EntityB_audit` does not exist. This seems like it's trying to audit them as a single table, which I do not want.
2. I have tried applying `@Audited(targetAuditMode = elationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)` to each side. If applied only in `EntityA`, I get the above error. If applied only in `EntityB`, nothing changes. If applied in both, I get the error above. If applied to neither, I get the error above.
3. I suspect the `entity_a_id` is null in `entity_b_audit` because the id isn't generated until EntityA hits the DB. `entity_a_id` is auto-incrementing in the `entity_a` table.
4. Using `hibernate-envers-5.4.32.Final.jar`

Ultimately, I would like for `entity_a_id` to not be null in `entity_b_audit`. Alternatively, if I could somehow get `entity_a_uuid` to be captured instead, that would also suffice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You marked the column as `insertable = false, updatable = false`, so there is nothing to audit here, because Hibernate can never change the value of that column.